# Can maplist([X]>>(test(X,Xs)) see variable in outer in scope?

Tags: prolog

```
?- maplist([X]>>(member(X,[1,2])),
        [1,2]).
true
```

but:

```
?- X2s=[1,2],
   X1s=[1,2],
   maplist([X]>>(member(X,X1s)),
           X2s).
X1s = X2s, X2s = [1, 2]
```

X1s is not grounded, despite being grounded.

Here a notebook testing it: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/ungrounded%20in%20map.swinb

What's up with that?

Comment: Which Prolog are you using? Since `X1s = X2s` and `X2s` is grounded, then isn't `X1s` grounded?

Comment: SWI (via SWISH).
https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/ungrounded%20in%20map.swinb

Comment: `X1s = X2s, X2s = [1, 2]` is just SWI Prolog's way of saying, `X1s = [1, 2], X2s = [1, 2]`. In either case, `X1s` is grounded.

Comment: Good point. We get the same for ?- X=1, Y=1, X=Y.
----> X = Y, Y = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not get confused by the SWI-Prolog variable-name-aliasing

```
?- debug(foo),X2s=[1,2],
   X1s=[1,2],
   maplist([X]>>(debug(foo,"Testing ~q",[X]),member(X,X1s)),X2s).

Warning: foo: no matching debug topic (yet)
% Testing 1
% Testing 2
X2s = X1s, X1s = [1, 2] ;
false.
```

just means

- The query succeeds with the `X` printed as expected (so `X1s` and `X2s` are visible inside`maplist/3`.
- `X2s` and `X1s` are aliases for the same term (which is true), `[1, 2]` (also true).
- A retry fails.

Actually, `maplist/3` doesn't "shield" from any variables visible in the clause context, but the [yall lambda notation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall) has a way of specifying that the lambda expression `>>` is referring to variables in the outer context, `{}`:

```
?- debug(foo),X2s=[1,2],
   X1s=[1,2],
   maplist({X1s}/[X]>>(debug(foo,"Testing ~q",[X]),member(X,X1s)),X2s).
```

Although the `{X1s}` properly doesn't do anything here. I don't know where it does ... "shielding off variables" is not properly done in Prolog (IMHO, it should, especially in `bagof/3` and `setgof/3`)

Comment: I drilled into the lack of effect of `{X1s}` a bit and its due to autoloading/precompilation issues. On the SWI-Prolog toplevel, there is no need to write the "bracy part". That is an error, one should really add it. I added a comment to the page for [`library(yall)`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)