# How to use maplist and [..]>> with grounded variable?

Tags: prolog

Am confused about grounding, variable scope and the use of maplist:

```
label_text(Prefix, N, String):-
    string_concat(Prefix, N, String).

texts1(LabelTexts) :-
    Indexes = [1,2,3],
    maplist([I,Label]>>(label_text("prefix", I, Label)),
            Indexes, 
            LabelTexts).


% Just move "prefix" into a variable
texts2(LabelTexts) :-
    Indexes = [1,2,3],
    Pre = "prefix",
    maplist([I,Label]>>(label_text(Pre, I, Label)), 
            Indexes,
            LabelTexts).
```

```
? texts1(X).
X = ["prefix1", "prefix2", "prefix3"]
```

```
? texts2(X).
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [4] string_concat(_1524,1,_1528)
   [3] label_text(_1582,1,_1586) at  line 2
   [1] '__aux_maplist/3___aux_yall_d3bf4db62cf9a7bb20e7cebd5ed8444c8d235d43+0'([1,2|...],[_1674|_1676]) at  line 8

Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

label_text's first parameter should have been grounded in both cases (right?).
But from the error it look it was provided a variable. What's up with that?

SWISH notebook https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/maplist%20example.swinb

Related to: [Can maplist([X]>>(test(X,Xs)) see variable in outer in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61763971/can-maplistxtestx-xs-see-variable-in-outer-in-scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can ... under certain circumstances.

You should use the "bracy notation" `{Pre}` to declare variables of the inner scope as "free" and linked to the outer scope:

```
texts2(LabelTexts) :-
    Indexes = [1,2,3],
    Pre = "prefix",
    maplist({Pre}/[I,Label]>>(label_text(Pre, I, Label)), 
            Indexes,
            LabelTexts).
```

See my comment at the end of this page:

https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall

There is a little interaction with autoloading.

If you forget to add the "bracy part" of a lambda expression in an environment that performs autoloading of `library(yall)` (i.e. the toplevel), things work fine -- although they should not:

```
bracy(L)   :- X=a, maplist({X}/[Y,Z]>>atom_concat(X,Y,Z), [1,2,3,4], L).
nobracy(L) :- X=a, maplist([Y,Z]>>atom_concat(X,Y,Z), [1,2,3,4], L).  % FAULTY
```

At the toplevel, add them with `[user].`. Then both predicates work.

However, if you run them like this, explicitly loading `library(yall)` and `library(apply)`:

```
?- use_module(library(apply)).
true.

?- use_module(library(yall)).
true.

?- [user].
|: bracy(L)   :- X=a, maplist({X}/[Y,Z]>>atom_concat(X,Y,Z), [1,2,3,4], L).
|: nobracy(L) :- X=a, maplist([Y,Z]>>atom_concat(X,Y,Z), [1,2,3,4], L).
|: % user://1 compiled 0.01 sec, 5 clauses
true.
```

... then the code is more picky and `nobracy/1` isn’t working:

```
?- bracy(X).
X = [a1, a2, a3, a4].

?- nobracy(X).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Comment: In the first case, the `X=a` goal is called before the call to `maplist/3`. Therefore, there are only two variables, both lambda local parameters, when `maplist/3` is called. In the second case, the `maplist/3` goal and its lambda expression argument are expanded independently of the `X=a` goal, which leads to the instantiation error (call `listing(nobracy/1)` to understand why).